# Google Apps Script jquery autocomplete not displaying <ul> list when typing in characters

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a fairly complex form using Google Apps Script HtmlService and jquery.  I'm trying to use the autocomplete feature from jquery, and its working somewhat.  If I start typing in "ja", then using the down arrow key it will scroll through results.  However what it should be doing is displaying them in a  list dynamically like it does locally.  There is an error in the console, but don't know what to make of it:

Error 4089105213-maestro_htmlapp_bin_maestro_htmlapp.js:55
pl 4089105213-maestro_htmlapp_bin_maestro_htmlapp.js:55

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>
</div><!-- End demo -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to be behaving as expected... what's the problem exactly? http://jsfiddle.net/DWvmK/

Comment: @shadow As the user stated, if you try this code locally (or anywhere else that is not Apps Script) it will work as expected. The issue only shows up when the code is cajoled. @ user you should open an issue on [apps script issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Yes when its cajoled it doesn't work quite right.  2058 put in the apps script issue tracker.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu He did not say "cajoled" anywhere in his question.

Comment: @shadow I agree, he didn't. But it's just how google-apps-script works. Client-side code is always cajoled. And if it works on jsfiddle, that is usually the problem.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu I think its a GAS issue anyways and not just Caja.  It works as expected when cajoling directly in Caja playground [http://caja.appspot.com/](http://caja.appspot.com/)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But it may still be Caja, just an older version of it. Right now Apps Script is using 5097m, and on the playground you're testing under 5122.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu - How can you tell which version HtmlService is using?  Do you just look at the source for 'cajolerVersion':'5114m'?  Looks like it was updated to 5114 maybe?

Comment: Yes, I just inspect the page code. I actually looked at the script tag, the link has the version on it. It was updated indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you load the Jquery resources (Javascript and CSS files) using HTTPS instead of HTTP it works inside google apps scripts.

```
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```